# How to fix the file renaming error using a variable in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, pandas

I am trying to rename a bunch of files by appending a variable to it. The variable value for each file is obtained from a column called "APPEND" in the dataframe df (where the FILE_ID in the df matches with the file name). When I run the code, I get the following error:

```
OSError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: 'C:/Users/Downloads/Input/\\DOC_001.xlsx' -> "C:/Users/Downloads/Input/\\DOC_001_1    File Suffix, dtype: object.xlsx"
```

```
import os
import glob

dir = 'file path'

for root, directories, files in os.walk(dir):
        for file in files:
            filename, extension = os.path.splitext(file)
            add_text = df.loc[df.FILE_ID.eq(filename), 'APPEND']
            os.rename(os.path.join(root, file), os.path.join(root, "{}_{}{}".format(filename, add_text, extension)))
```

However, I am able to rename the files if I simply use a variable with a fixed string value. So, the following code works:

```
import os
import glob

add_text = "File suffix"
dir = 'file path'

for root, directories, files in os.walk(dir):
        for file in files:
            filename, extension = os.path.splitext(file)
            os.rename(os.path.join(root, file), os.path.join(root, "{}_{}{}".format(filename, add_text, extension)))
```

Please note I have not included the code for the pandas dataframe here.

Comment: can you please print(add_text)

Comment: what text do you append ? How looks filename without appended text ? It seems you append `File Suffix, dtype: object` and `:` is not allowed in filename.

Comment: @BenoitdeMenthière Here is what I get when I print add_text value from the dataframe:

1    ATTENTION - THIS FILE IS CONFIDENTIAL
Name: APPEND, dtype: object

Comment: I think I figured it out. I needed to convert each add_text using item().

Comment: Can you provide a minimal example of the DataFrame (`df.head()`)? copy and paste it as text then format as code. Or a fake DataFrame that will still reproduce the error. Please read [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure it out.

I was appending a series to the file name. Instead, I needed to first extract the actual item from it by using `item()`

Here is the modification:

```
add_text = df.loc[df.FILE_ID.eq(filename), 'APPEND'].item()
```